# css pseudo selector :not for div that don't have div as child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this scenario

```
  <div>
      <div>
        <i>italic text</i>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I am seeking to choose just the first div, the one that does not contain `<i>` as children. I am out of curiosity about how to do it the `:not` pseudo-selector. Some examples that didn't work for me:

```
- div > :not(i)
- div:not(div > i) 
- div:not( > i)
- div:not(div > i)
- :not(div > i)
```

Any ideas of how to achieve it without class selectors and with `:not` selector?

Comment: All these would select the `i` element, not the `div`. It isn't possible with pure CSS to select (or filter) a parent element, which the `div` *is*  in relation to the `i`. You'll need javascript/jQuery for this.